# Apache Forbidden on Virtual Directory

Tags: apache2

I have been trying to configure my Apache to list the log files that are stored in **/var/log/squid/** so that I can download them from the server to my local PC if required. I have configured the Alias as follows;

```
Alias /squid/ "/var/log/squid/"
<Directory "/var/log/squid/">
    Options None
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

But I keep getting the 403 Forbidden error message when I try to browse to the directory.

Apache2 Log Files (CentOS)

```
172.16.200.132 - - [10/May/2014:14:34:01 +0100] "GET /squid/ HTTP/1.1" 403 288 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36"
172.16.200.132 - - [10/May/2014:14:34:01 +0100] "GET /squid/ HTTP/1.1" 403 288 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36"
172.16.200.132 - - [10/May/2014:14:34:01 +0100] "GET /squid/ HTTP/1.1" 403 288 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36"
172.16.200.132 - - [10/May/2014:14:34:01 +0100] "GET /squid/ HTTP/1.1" 403 288 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36"
172.16.200.132 - - [10/May/2014:14:34:01 +0100] "GET /squid/ HTTP/1.1" 403 288 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36"
172.16.200.132 - - [10/May/2014:14:34:01 +0100] "GET /squid/ HTTP/1.1" 403 288 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36"
172.16.200.132 - - [10/May/2014:14:34:01 +0100] "GET /squid/ HTTP/1.1" 403 288 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36"
```

Does anyone have any suggestions, I have tried changing the user Apache runs under to `admin` which is a user that has full access to the **/var/log/squid/** directory but doesn't have access to any system services **/etc/init.d/** or the ability to run commands such as (`halt`, `service`).

Any suggestion please.

Error Log from Apache

```
[Mon May 12 17:53:11 2014] [error] [client 172.16.200.132] (13)Permission denied: Can't open directory for index: /var/log/squid/
```

Comment: Please post message from apache2 error log file.

Comment: The log file is posted above 172.16.200.132 - - [10/May/2014:14:34:01 +0100] "GET /squid/ HTTP/1.1" 403 288 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36"

Answer (score 0):

From the log OP posted, the interesting part is `)Permission denied: Can't open directory for index:`.

To solve this, change line `Options None` to `Options +Indexes`

References: [official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options)